# Regional server read from nearby MongoDB cluster node and write to remote MongoDB master

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-cluster

We plan to set up a global MongoDB cluster across 2 different data centers. The MongoDB master will be inside the AWS China data center and there will be a read-only node in AWS Singapore.

How do we specify our Singapore server to read from the MongoDB node in AWS Singapore and write into the MongoDB Master node in the AWS China data center?

Comment: I'm not familiar in details about cross region replica set configuration. But as long as you have a master in China and secondaries in Singapore, you should be able to specify which server to use for read via readpreference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/. Write is supported only to master

Comment: Also look at [tag sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference-tags/#read-preference-tag-sets)